# Make the element visible when scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, visibility

I'm confused as to how to make an element be visible when scrolled by the user, here is my code:

```js
var benefitpub = document.getElementById('pubbox');
var advbox2 = document.getElementById('advbox');

if (document.body.scrollTop > benefitpub.getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px') {
    benefitpub.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
if (document.body.scrollTop > advbox2.getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px') {
    advbox2.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
#advbox, #pubbox{
    margin-top: 500px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="advbox">
    Hello This is advbox
</div>

<div id="pubbox">
    Hello this is Pubbox
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to change a few things, firstly, you need a `onscroll` event handler so you can check when the user is scrolling the window.

```js
var benefitpub = document.getElementById('pubbox');
var advbox2 = document.getElementById('advbox');

window.onscroll = function () {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > benefitpub.getBoundingClientRect().top) {
        benefitpub.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
     benefitpub.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > advbox2.getBoundingClientRect().top) {
        advbox2.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
     advbox2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

```css
#advbox, #pubbox{
    margin-top: 500px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="advbox">
    Hello This is advbox
</div>

<div id="pubbox">
    Hello this is Pubbox
</div>
```

Also, note that I am getting the `scrollTop` of the `documentElement` which is the `<html>` tag, not the body since that returns `0`.

Comment: Would also suggest to create it as a separate function, which should also be called on dom load, cause browser could be already scrolled down on page reload.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , i have made few changes to your code snipet

- onscroll event added
- changed benefitpub.style.visibility = 'visible'; to benefitpub.style.visibility = 'inherit';

```js
var benefitpub = document.getElementById('pubbox');
var advbox2 = document.getElementById('advbox');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > benefitpub.getBoundingClientRect().top - 200) {
        benefitpub.style.visibility = 'inherit';
    }
    if (document.body.scrollTop > advbox2.getBoundingClientRect().top - 200) {
        advbox2.style.visibility = 'inherit';
    }
});
```

```css
#advbox, #pubbox,#pubbox1{
    margin-top: 500px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="advbox">
    Hello This is advbox
</div>

<div id="pubbox">
    Hello this is Pubbox
</div>

<div id="pubbox1">
    Hello this is Pubbox
</div>
```

Comment: Not bad but the problem is if the visitor screen is big and the scroll is just have small distance then the function will not work, maybe you try to zoom out your browser, if #pubbox and #advbox be inherit after zoom out then it's perfect but if not then i think not too good. Maybe see this as example: https://www.clixtoo.com/

Comment: you can plus or minus on this line document.body.scrollTop > benefitpub.getBoundingClientRect().top as per your requirement